# How to to draw a necklace of n circles internaly tangent to a given circle

Tags: geometry, circles

The below images show n number of circles inside of a circle all inner circles tangent to the surface of the outer circle.

[image: 3 circles inside of a circle]

[image: 4 circles inside of a circle]

[image: 5 circles inside of a circle]

So lets say I have an outer circle in P(x,y) coordinates with radius R. I want to draw n inner as the images above. So what would be their center coordinates and their radius?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I have very poor math skills. The best visualisation for my question is what I've attached to here. I am able to find the positions for 4 circles with hypothenus. Maybe I can try my best to find for 3 circles version with some trigonometry but instead of this I need a more generalized solution. This is not homework to solve. So maybe a clue to solving approach or some topics which I need to cover also help me to solve the issue. Thanks for advice too! I'll check all the links

Comment: Give a name to the different entities. radius $R$ for the exterior circle, radius $r$ for the internal radii, distance $d$ from any of the n centers to the origin. Start with a regular n-gon inscribed in a circle with radius $d$ and find formulas on the net for the sidelength $s$ of such a n-gon which is to be set equal to $2r$. Then connect the different variables $n,R,r,d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a picture below. It is trivial to see that the angle between the origins of two circles side by side is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Then the angle $\angle{AOB}=\frac{\pi}{n}$. Now we can use the law of sines: $\frac{r}{\sin(\pi/n)}=\frac{|OB|}{\sin(\pi/2)} \implies |OB|=\frac{r}{\sin(\pi/n)}$. Let's call the radius of big circle $R$. Then, $R=|OB|+r = \frac{r}{\sin(\pi/n)} + r$. Then $r=\frac{R}{\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/n)}+1}$. So, we have the radius of small circles. Let polar coordinates of one of the centers be $|R-r|(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)$. Now we can find the coordinates of other centers as well since we know the angle between them is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. [image]

Comment: Thanks @Sunay! It works as expected. Is there a way to apply it to a sphere instead of circle?

Comment: I think we can apply the same idea to find the radii of small spheres. For the coordinates we'll have to use spherical coordinate system. I did not do the calculation though. This is just an idea.